# How to Get Row Count of Table That May or May Not Exist?

Tags: sql

I have an issue where I have two possible tables that may contain the data I need. I have accounted for this using a temp table, and an `if-else if` that fills the temp table from the appropriate table:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = "table1") BEGIN
    --Fill temp table.
END ELSE BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = "table2") BEGIN
        -- Fill temp table.
    END
END
```

This works great as long as `table1` no longer exists. However, I have come to learn that the old table still exists and contains no data thus causing an issue with my query not returning the proper results.

I have achieved a workaround; however, this will only work if the table exists, if the table does not exist (there are cases of this) then the query will not execute:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = "table1") AND
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) > 0 BEGIN
    -- Fill temp table.
END
```

How do I get the row count of a table that may or may not exist?

***Other Useful Notes***: I am using `SSMS 2016`.

***Good Suggestions***: A fellow user stated that I should give `EXEC` a try; I am more than willing to go this route if need be. Our IA guy doesn't really like this approach and there is additional validation that would have to be done in order to make him happy but the quick and dirty version would be:

```
DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = "table1") AND
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) > 0 BEGIN
        -- Fill temp table.
    END'
EXEC sp_executesql @CMD;
```

Another good attempt would be to verify the existence of the new table first and prioritize it instead, however this does not answer the question behind this post; but for those with a similar situation this would work as well:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = "table2") BEGIN
    --Fill temp table.
END ELSE BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = "table1") BEGIN
        -- Fill temp table.
    END
END
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?  Also, it sounds like possible bad database design that you would not even know if a certain table exists.  Ideally, this should be a rare event.

Comment: I am using SSMS 2016. This is a rare event, I'm not sure my co-worker realizes this for new versions of the database but I will be making it known today.

Comment: You can probably construct and [EXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the select count instead, so that it doesn't syntax-check the SQL first.

Comment: It's not the SSMS version that matters but the version of the SQL Server that's connected to. Which may also be 2016 though.

Comment: @Rup this is a good point and I am open to going this route if I absolutely need to. I would like to see if there are other options on the table too. Our IA guy doesn't really like `EXEC`.

Comment: Why you need a temporal table if all you want is a `COUNT()`?

Comment: I am loading a lot of data into the temp table and do not wish to copy that sub-query over. I need to verify the table has rows if it exists prior to filling the temp table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can query the row count from sys.tables too:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = 'table1'
                                   AND OBJECTPROPERTYEX([object_id], 'Cardinality') > 0)
```

This and a few alternative approaches are here on [the SQLAuthority blog](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/05/24/sql-server-find-row-count-every-table-database-efficiently/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want fix your workaround just split the `IF`

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = 'table1') 
BEGIN
   IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) > 0 
   BEGIN
         -- Fill temp table.
   END
END
```

Comment: Throws an "Invalid column name 'table1'". Replace the double quotes around `table1` with single quotes in the first query to fix this.